# JSTL in Javascript for Weblogic 11g

Tags: jstl, weblogic11g

We are planning to convert the project from Weblogic 10.x to 11g. In many places, we used JSTL in javascript. Will it be a problem during the conversion? Does Weblogic 11g supports JSTL in javascript? I heard from someone that it doesn't? I want to confirm it.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

JSTL is the JSP Standard Tag Library. It can be used in JSPs. What the JSP generates (HTML, XML, JavaScript, plain text, whatever) is irrelevant: the JSTL can be used in JSPs.